# Enable https for play framework

Tags: https, playframework

I wish to enable https on my site which is based on play framework.

I have the below settings in conf/application.conf as described in the documentation for play version 2.3.x in https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ConfiguringHttps

```
# https settings
https.port=9443
https.keyStorePath=/home/username/.keystore/example.jks
https.keyStoreType=JKS
https.keyStorePassword=mysecurepassword
https.keyStoreAlgorithm=RSA
```

However, when I hit https://example.com:9443/ I get the error "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" in Chrome. Is there something wrong in my configuration?

Appreciate any pointers/help on this.

Note:
I have created the keystore and installed the certificate there.

Comment: It's not possible in the `conf/application.conf`, you have to use those -D parameters, like `-Dhttps.port=9443`.